# Append Table row to existing Table PHP, Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I'm trying to make a Table where the user is able to see some data from a database.

To do this im using this js code to append a row for every entity:

```
     function append(id, name){
    $table_body = $('#tbody');
    //html of the table row
    $table_row = $('<tr class="edit" id="' + id + '"> <td></td><div class="checkbox"> <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbutton">checkbox</label></div><td>' + name + '</td></tr>');
    //append row
    $table_body.append($table_row);
    $('#avatartable').show();
  }
```

with that code I'm gettin this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

I'm pretty sure the dollar sign is needed though and I don't know what I can do now.

Comment: Link jQuery to the document. Maybe worth of nothing, but JS variable names are typically not starting with `$`, and instead of `_` s, camel case is used, currently your code looks more like invalid PHP. The future developers of your code will hate their job because of such conventions ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can NOT combine PHP and JavaScript at the same time in a function (execept to write the js code with echo or something similar)!
-Php is a back-end language (executed in server)
-JS is a front-end language (executed in browser)

if all you want is to display data from database into a HTML table just put a php script inside the tbody, loop through your array an echo the rows
something like

```
foreach($array as $value)
    echo '<tr><td>'.$value.'</td><td>...</td></tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Include jQuery script in your html.

Insert this line inseide  in your html file

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've already included JQuery but it doesn't seem to work anyway.

Comment: Make sure that this link is before (in above lines) your javascript file. Also make sure you wrapped your enitre jQuery code inside $( document ).ready(function() {
    
});